# C++ How to get the status in multi-thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have 3 threads that maybe run at the same time, now I want to control their running logic as below.

1) thread1, thread2, thread3 are 3 kinds of time-consuming thread, I want only run 1 at the time. 
and thread1 is also exclusive with itself, it means if one thread1 is running, the second thread1 will also not run.

2) I want to know current running thread information, (ex, which kind of thread is running)
for example, when thread1 is running, now before run thread2, I want to check current whether there is a thread running, and I also want to know currently which thread is running (in this sample, I want to know thread1 is running), if there is thead1 running, I will not run thread2, and return status.

Base on above, I defined below lock class.

```
enum LOCK_TYPE{
    Type_UnLock = 0,
    Type_Lock_1,
    Type_Lock_2,
    Type_Lock_3,
};

//uCurLockType is a reference, when locked by others, 
//it will store current lock type and return.
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> g_lock(g_mutex, std::defer_lock);

bool CXXXLock::Lock(LOCK_TYPE uToLockType, LOCK_TYPE& uCurLockType)
{
    if(m_uLockType != LOCK_TYPE::Type_UnLock)
    {
        uCurLockType = m_uLockType;
        return false;
    }
    if(g_lock.try_lock())
    {
        m_uLockType = uToLockType;
        g_lock.unlock();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        uCurLockType = m_uLockType;
        return false;
    }
}

bool CXXXLock::Unlock()
{
   if(g_lock.try_lock())
   {
       m_uLockType = LOCK_TYPE::Type_UnLock;
       g_lock.unlock();
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }

}
```

in thread1 proc function, it will call as below. it will also similar as thread2/thread3 proc function, GetInstance() is a singleton, and will get the unique global object.

```
unsigned thread1proc(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    LOCK_TYPE uToLockType = LOCK_TYPE::Type_Lock_1, uCurLockType = LOCK_TYPE::Type_UnLock;
    if(false == GetInstance().Lock(uToLockType, uCurLockType))
    {
        //it is locked by other thead, uCurLockType means which kind of thread lock it.
        //store current lock type uCurLockType and exit this thread.
        return;
    }

    //  do thread logic

    GetInstanct().Unlock();
    return;
}
```

After I testing, it seems work ok, However, I want to know whether this is standard way to do this. 
Any comments is appreciated.

------2013.8.23 Update CXXXLock implementation--------

------2031.8.36--------

It seems I have defined some wrong function that will make confused, For my requirement, it seems looks like CXXXXLock::GetExclusiveFlag instead of CXXXLock::Lock function as it has no lock function actually. and the thread should follow this specification before do real action.

Comment: `I want only run 1 at the time` Why do you need multiple threads then?

Comment: hm, you can think there are 3 modules, and they will launch each thread, and we do not want to they run at the same time. we could not control each module when they will launch thread.

Comment: What you are doing seems like a [WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Comment: Does your wording show what you mean? Is thread1 a thread function that is executed by several threads? Since you write about a "second thread1" it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -- I want only run 1 at the time
>
> -- Why do you need multiple threads then?
>
> -- hm, you can think there are 3 modules, and they will launch each thread, and we do not want to they run at the same time. we could not
> control each module when they will launch thread.

I can think of one possible reason for threads to want not to run at the same time. It is the situation when they operate on the same shared resource. In that case to prevent data-races you can use for example a `mutex` object. Thread-1 locks the `mutex`, performs some operations on shared data and then unlocks it. Thread-2 will try to lock that mutes and will wait for the thread-1 to unlock the `mutex` if it's locked.

In the comments you've mentioned that you have to synchronize several types of operations. In that case you should use N mutex objects for N types of locks (operations). If mutex_1 is locked that means that operation_1 is running now. If mutex_2 is locked that means that operation_2 is running now. If mutex_n is un-locked that means that operation_n is not running now

Comment: hm, your scenario is one story, there is another story, for example, one thread is do scan action, another one is do update action, we do not want to scan and update do at the same time. and when scanning, Update action just check it, and skip update this time, this is current what wants to do. Thanks!

Comment: @user1337961 sceanrion you've described is solved the same very way. Threads that must execute separately try to acquire the control over a shared `mutex`. If they lock it, no other thread will execute untill the first one unlocks it.

Comment: Current requirement is that other thread does not want to wait, just skip it this time.

Comment: @user1337961 it's very easy: `std::mutex::try_lock()` returns `bool` depending on whether it's possible to lock `mutex` immediately or not. If it returns `false` that means that the `mustex` is locked and the other thread is performing some operation.

Comment: Yes, try_lock can know whether is lock or not, however, if wants to know lock type, it could not support. as in first post, it can get uCurLockType

Comment: @user1337961 you should use `N` `mutex` objects for `N` types of locks (operations). If `mutex_1` is locked that means that `operation_1` is running now. If `mutex_2` is locked that means that `operation_2` is running now. If `mutex_n` is un-locked that means that `operation_n` is not running now.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Once more, How about my solution, is it ok or something defect.

Comment: @user1337961 your code is just not thread safe. `CXXXLock::Lock` doesn't hold the lock but unlocks it after function end (hope you know what happens when `lock_guard` is destroyed). So your assumption `//it is not locked by others, so I can get the lock, and run thread` is wrong since other thread could already lock the mutex.

Comment: @user1337961 anyway do I would suggest you not to reinvent a bicycle but to use `n` `mutex` objects an to `try_lock` them.

Comment: @user1337961 ^ this would make the code less error-prone and more readable, logical and understandable and compact.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will consider it.

Comment: @user1337961 if our conversation did helped you in some way, answer-accept + up-vote would be appreciated.

Comment: About your said not thread safe, as it has used m_uLockType to keep current lock type, when lock_guard destroyed, even other thread hold the thread, it will also return false at CXXXLock::Lock, and return from thread, I think this is not a problem.

Comment: @user1337961 the assumption of `it is not locked by others, so I can get the lock, and run thread` is wrong because it theoretically **can** be locked by some other thread without a check (directly). I would not suggest you not to go on such a thin ice. And again, this is not thread safe. Thread safety is when no race-conditions can occur even theoretically.

Comment: Update CXXXLock class implementation.